# launch a fragment with result using navigation architecture components

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, navigation, navigation-architecture

Below is how i am `navigating` from `fragment A` to `fragment B` using android `navigation`

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        int viewId = view.getId();

        if (viewId == R.id.btn_proceed) {
          
          Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.fragmentB);

        }
    }
```

I would like to achieve returning of results from `fragmentB` to `fragmentA` where for example fragmentB has an **EditText** that a user keys in text and is returned to fragmentA and set to **TextView** using android architecture navigation components

Comment: Did you read the [documentation on returning a result](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-programmatic#returning_a_result)?

Comment: @ianhanniballake let me try

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation on returning a result](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-programmatic#returning_a_result) i was able to achieve what i was asking with the code below.

Declare a **NavController**

```
private NavController navController;
```

Inside `onViewCreated` method

```
navController = Navigation.findNavController(view);

        MutableLiveData<String> liveData = Objects.requireNonNull(navController.getCurrentBackStackEntry())
                .getSavedStateHandle()
                .getLiveData("key");
```

To get result in **FragmentA** from **FragmentB**

```
 liveData.observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), s -> {

           tvResult.setText(s);

        });
```

In **FragmentB** do the following, for example when a button is clicked

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        int viewId = view.getId();

        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(view);

        if (viewId == R.id.btn_returnResult) {

            String etText = editText.getText().toString();

            Objects.requireNonNull(navController.getPreviousBackStackEntry())
                    .getSavedStateHandle().set("key", etText);

            navController.navigateUp();

        }
    }
```